# Создать значение если оно не найдено

Tags: c#

В ruby есть `find or create`. Как в c# сделать такое же? Единственное что нашёл, это такой хелпер.

```
public static class DbSetExtensions
{
    public static T AddIfNotExists<T>(this DbSet<T> dbSet
         , T entity, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null)
         where T : class, new()
    {
        var exists = predicate != null ? dbSet.Any(predicate) : dbSet.Any();
        return !exists ? dbSet.Add(entity) : null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Опишите что он должен делать? Т.к. не все знакомы с ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по смыслы фразы *find or create*, как-то так

```
public static class DbSetExtensions
{
    public static T FindOrCreate<T>(this DbSet<T> dbSet
         , T entity, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
         where T : class, new()
    {
        var found = dbSet.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
        if (found != null)
        {
            return found;
        }
        else
        {
            return dbSet.Add(entity).Entity;   
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Последний блок `if` можно заменить `return found ?? dbSet.Add(entity).Entity;`